# Best way to get specific value in two table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on this problem, let me explain. 
I have two table one called `league` that have this structure:

```
id|leagueCode|Country|League
0 | B1       |Germany|Bundesliga
1 | I1       | Italy |Serie A
```

another table called `soccerseason` have this structure:

```
id|caption   |League |years
 0|Bundesliga|B1     |2014
 1| Serie A  |   I1  |2014
```

Now, I want eet the `league` values from the `League` table. In particular Bundesliga and Serie A. How you can see in the `soccerseason` table each value have a years, so I want select Bundesliga for the year `2014` and Nation `Germany`. Because my app, have this selection structure:

Select year: 2014
Select nation: Germany

I'm aspect a result like this: `Bundesliga`

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm just glad that I don't have to work with this insane structure

Comment: Please use the search before posting a new question. Especially if you have the feeling that the answer is more or less trivial, there is a high chance that existing Q&A material already eixsts on site. If you only find existing material that is only close but does not answer your question, please reference it and explain how your question is different to it and why it didn't make it for your case.

Comment: Salvatore sometimes we don't sugar coat things here. It was a fun loving comment from @Strawberry, unlike yours. So do yourself a favor, and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to join the tables together using a column that exists in both tables.  From your example, I am guessing `soccerseason.League` is the same as `league.leagueCode`, in which case you can join the tables using this column, and return the results as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM league l
LEFT JOIN soccerseason s ON (s.League = l.leagueCode)
```

Comment: Good example, thank you.

Comment: Why I get: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'l.leagueCode' in 'on clause' ?